# How to make Geo IP lookup command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a command to look up IPs via a JSON Api.
I'm wanting to make the output more human-readable, in otherwords, my issue is the formatting.

Organization: Cloudflare

City: CityNameHere

Country: Australia

Region: Queensland

ISP: Cloudflare DNS Resolver

Timezone: Aus/Bris

Status: Success.

My current code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');
module.exports = (client, message,args) => {
snekfetch.get(`http://ip-api.com/json/${args}` ).then(r => {
var string =JSON.stringify(r.body);
let Geo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTimestamp()
.setThumbnail(`https://image.ibb.co/kcFJ09/resolver.png`)
.setTitle(`**Deluxo Puller - GeoIP Lookup**`)
.setDescription(`**__GeoIP Lookup Information__**\n**Looked Up IP**: ${args}\n${string}`)
.setFooter(`Resolved By: ${message.author.tag}`)

message.channel.send({embed: Geo})
```

This is the outcome:
http://prntscr.com/knz47k

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: And what's the problem? Currently you're merely stating that you're working on a thing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add an image of whats happening.
I'm wanting to lay everything out smoothly so for ex:

(as) Organization: BlahBlah
City: Blah
Country: Australia
Region: Queensland
ISP: Random ISP
Timezone: Aus/Bris
Status: Success.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what the problem is.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. The response you're getting is exactly what you want.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer Yes, exactly, Im wanting to make it human readable as the way its outputting its nasty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.body` is already an object, so just use properties on it. In this example I show the ASN and city of the IP address. You can add on as needed.

```
snekfetch.get(`http://ip-api.com/json/${args}`).then(r => {
  let Geo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(`https://image.ibb.co/kcFJ09/resolver.png`)
    .setTitle(`**Deluxo Puller - GeoIP Lookup**`)
    .setDescription(`**__GeoIP Lookup Information__**
**Looked Up IP**: ${args}
**ASN**: ${r.body.as}
**City**: ${r.body.city}`)
    .setFooter(`Resolved By: ${message.author.tag}`);

  message.channel.send({ embed: Geo });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so helpful :D